# How to use cURL in Windows to upload a file to Alfresco?

Tags: php, windows, http, curl, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to upload a file to Alfresco WS restful, using a command as follow:

```
C:\Users\user>curl -v -k -X POST --user admin:admin  -F filedata=C:/temp/wpapper.pdf  -F siteid=documents  -F     containerid=documentLibrary  -F uploaddirectory=PUBLIC  -F     filename=wpapper.pdf  -F contenttype="application/pdf"      http://10.1.1.55:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.1.1.55...
* Connected to 10.1.1.55 (10.1.1.55) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /alfresco/service/api/upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.1.1.55:8080
> Authorization: Basic Z2xvbWFyb246c2VxMDk4
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 715
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5ee452c8955311dc
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 362
< Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 14:03:47 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{
    "status" :
  {
    "code" : 400,
    "name" : "Bad Request",
    "description" : "Request sent by the client was syntactically     incorrect."
  },

  "message" : "Required parameters are missing",
  "exception" : "",

  "callstack" :
  [

  ],

  "server" : "Community v5.1.0 (r122274-b3) schema 9.016",
  "time" : "18/05/2016 10:03:47"
}

* Closing connection 0
```

[Alfresco's manual for File upload](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html):

> Upload file content and meta-data into repository.
>
> ```
> POST /alfresco/service/api/upload
> ```
>
> HTML form data
>
> - filedata, (mandatory) HTML type file
> - You must specify one of:
>
>   - destination (the folder NodeRef where the node will be created)
>   - updateNodeRef (the NodeRef of an existing node that will be updated)
>   - siteid and containerid (the Site name and the container in that site >where the document will be created).
> - uploaddirectory - name of the folder (either in the site container or the destination) where the document will be uploaded. This folder must already exist
> - description - Description for a version update (versionDescription)
> - contenttype - The content type that this document should be specialised to
> - majorversion
> - overwrite
> - thumbnails
>
> Return content
>
> - nodeRef
>
> Return status: STATUS_OK (200)
>
> The web script description document specifies the following options:
>
> ```
> _________________________________________
> Value ------ Description
> ___________________________________________
>
> json -------> The default response format
>
> user -------> The authentication access
> required ---> The transaction level
> any   The format style
> ___________________________________________
> ```

PS.: The directory *"PUBLIC"* and site *"documents"* already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this would be to upload a file via Share using Chrome with the Developer tools open. On the Network -> XHR tab you'll see the upload request and can then right-click and select "Copy as cURL". You can then paste the cURL command and adapt it as necessary.